# Are .NET assemblies without strong names protected against accidental corruption?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, assemblies

Suppose I build a .NET assembly and don't have it signed with a strong name, then it is copied to some storage, then to another and then it ends up in production. If a bit or two of the assembly contents get accidentally changed (some hardware problem or something like that) is there a chance that .NET runtime doesn't notice it and still considers the assembly image valid?

Comment: Depends on the nature of the corruption, where it happened in the file and if the runtime decides to verify. I have seen a 4k block of data in a framework assembly get corrupted and not noticeably affect applications. We only noticed something was wrong when some builds failed (the corruption overlapped part of the custom attributes table causing them to loose their parent references and C# to see some 'out' parameters as 'ref' parameters).

Answer (score 6):

Write this program:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

compile it, run it...

Now open it in Notepad++, go to Find, select Extended research type, search for `H\0`... Find the `H NUL e NUL l`... and replace the `H` with a `X`... Save and relaunch...

```
Xello world!
```

Note that strong named assemblies aren't verified normally... Try to add a strong name... compile... run

```
sn -v yourprogram.exe
```

and check that it is correct...

now modify it... rerun the

```
sn -v yourprogram.exe
```

and see that the validation fails...

now try to run it... It runs correctly!

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713694.aspx)

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 3.5 Service Pack 1 (SP1), strong-name signatures are not validated when an assembly is loaded into a full-trust AppDomain object, such as the default AppDomain for the MyComputer zone.

Comment: Hang on, does that mean I can take a 3rd party signed assembly, modify it so that eg some aspect of it now calls into my code, and it'll still loadand run just fine? What's the point of signed assemblies if that's the case?

Comment: @DavidArno strong-name is primarily built to resolve the dll-hell... With strong name, you can have multiple assemblies with the same "human name" but that are produced by different companies. You can reactivate the assembly verification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a chance.

Let's turn the question on its head.

Can I arbitrarily change any one bit in the assembly and still execute/use it?

No, lots of bits and bytes are read during load and execution and most of them matter.

If text or numbers, basically data, changes, the chance goes way way down though not entirely to zero, depending on the exact data that changed.

So the answer to your question is that:

- The assembly might be able to load, and execute, though possibly with incorrect/odd results
- The assembly might not load

There is no guarantee either way, however.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by .net runtime won't notice it? 
.net runtime won't run dll verification if it is not strongly signed. It will try to load the dll. 
If the change corrupts the dll then dll load will fail.

Comment: Assemblies contain IL code. Suppose there's some instruction somewhere inside code and bits change such that it is changed into another still valid instruction. Will runtime just load and happily run this code?